# Fooling a c++ compiler. Passing int instead of a cont int into function

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, int

How can i pass an **int** into a function that is expecting a **const int**.

Or is there a way of modifying cont int value?

Edit: I Should have mentioned this earlier, i am using ccs c compiler that is used to program pic microcontroller. fprintf function takes **constant** stream as its first argument. It will only accept a constant int and throw a compilation error otherwise "Stream must be a constant in the valid range.".

Edit 2: Stream is a constant byte.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "fooling"... it works out of the box...

Comment: Even if it wasn't due to a copy ([like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=ec23bb2c98a244425399b82f81edd08b-3afcc3bc1f2cd10b247c33a6cde9edad)), not modifying a non-const data variable is still ok, so there's no reason not to accept it. On the other hand, modifying a const variable is, and the compiler will give you an error if you switch the const to `r` in the link.

Comment: It's not complaining about the `const`. It's complaining about being handed an `int` when it expects a `FILE*`. On a second thought, since this compiler does range checking you probably do need to provide a **compile time constant**. This, however, has nothing to do with the `const` modifier.

Comment: @IInspectable the streams are constant byte in this case. Compiler is happy if i pass a const uint_8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A top level `const` in a function parameter list is completely ignored, so

```
void foo(const int n);
```

is exactly the same as

```
void foo(int n);
```

So, you just pass an `int`.

The only difference is in the function *definition*, in which `n` is `const` in the first example, and mutable in the second. So this particular `const` can be seen as an implementation detail and should be avoided in a function *declaration*. For example, here we don't want to modify `n` inside of the function:

```
void foo(int n); // function declaration. No const, it wouldn't matter and might give the wrong impression

void foo(const int n) 
{
  // implementation chooses not to modify n, the caller shouldn't care.
}
```

Comment: I guess ccs c compiler is not a similar to native c as i thought.

Answer (score 4):

This requires no fooling. A function that expects an argument of type `const int` will happily accept an argument of type `int`.

The following code will work fine:

```
void MyFunction(const int value);

int foo = 5;
MyFunction(foo);
```

Because the argument is passed *by value*, the `const` is really rather meaningless. The only effect is has is to ensure that the function's local copy of the variable is not modified. The variable you pass to the function will *never* be modified, regardless of whether the argument  is taken as `const` or not.