# Why does a wrong override compile?

Tags: c++, mingw

I have this code :

```
class A
{
    virtual void operator()(std::complex<double>* const input_spectrum, 
                            double* const noise_spectrum) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
    virtual void operator()(std::complex<double>* input_spectrum, 
                            double* noise_spectrum) override;
}
```

I don't get why it compiles? The const qualifiers are different, so it should throw an error, doesn't it?. Running under MinGW 4.8

Comment: Top level qualifiers are ignored in function signatures.

Comment: Ah, get it, it's because it is a copy of the original pointer so any modification is not important, right ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683881/functions-with-const-arguments-overloading-follow-up

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier excatly... like foo(int) and foo(const int)

Comment: See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297790/fooling-a-c-compiler-passing-int-instead-of-a-cont-int-into-function/18297802#18297802).